# Сохранение контента приложения при отключении интернета

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток! У меня такая проблема: если в приложении залогиниться, походить по вкладкам, потом отключить интернет и снова вернуться в приложение, то контент не отображается, исходя из этого вопрос: можно ли как-то программно сохранять контент, чтобы при отключении интернета он не терялся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, можно, если реализовать свой велосипед подобный этому: [кеширование изображений на SD карте](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133239/).

Comment: хм...а как реализован механизм хранения контента, ну скажем, во вконтакте под андроид?Там тоже всё одним кэшированием обходится?

Comment: посмотрите исходники, которые я привел, там автор достаточно доступно описывает весь механизм. мне кажется, что для аудио и видео можно использовать все то же, что и для фото

Comment: спасибо, попробую